# Executando minha aplicação AngularJS em algum servidor

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho uma aplicação front-end consumindo uma api rails , mas sou novo nessa ideia de separar o front-end do back-end , minha api roda no localhost:3000, e meu front simplesmente é uma pasta que eu vou lá manualmente e abro minha página html, eu queria saber como eu executo o meu front direto do servidor ex: localhost:8000/front , se tem alguma forma de jogar meu front dentro do servidor rails na porta 8080, ou se eu executo no npm, eu não quero usar o xammp ou wamp,até por que quando eu fazer deploy eu não quero ter um servidor pra api e outro para o front, quero os dois no mesmo servidor mas em projetos diferentes.

Comment: Tu tens Python instalado? O Python tem um módulo que cria um servidor HTTP simples pra esse tipo de teste.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno mas ai é que tá , eu quero um que rode na msm plataforma do rails , se eu rodar no python vou ter q comprar um servidor que de suporte a python e rails

Comment: Pensei que era só pra desenvolvimento.

Comment: Você conseguiu uma resposta para sua pergunta?

Comment: Olá @durtto, então cara se você for usar o angular 2 tem o angular-cli dá uma olhada, no caso do 1 usei sem servidor mesmo.

Comment: Se você conseguiu uma resposta, coloca ela, assim pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o http-server do npm

```
 npm install -g http-server
```

Vá até a pasta da sua aplicação angular e digite

```
http-server -a localhost -p 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar sua aplicação na página index do Rails mesmo como se fosse uma página normal.

Sobre a porta do Rails, você pode rodar o comando `rails server -p 8080`.

Existem mais informações sobre o deploy aqui: [Deployment Aplicações Rails - Caelum](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-ruby-on-rails/apendice-deployment/#20-6-proxies-reversos)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ter muitos servidores rodando ao mesmo tempo e para IPs diferentes ainda.

#### Exemplo

```
rails s -p 8080 -b 0.0.0.0
```

> -p = Port
>
> -b = Bind Address